# how to demultiplex high frequency signals

Tags: switches, multiplexer, high-frequency

I am trying to demultiplex 4 MHz to 15 MHz signals with SN74LV4051ADR but there are some problems:

[image]

1- The senders come from uC and now with around 4 MHz but after some time of working, uC gets damaged and stops working (I do not know the reason!). I will use an external signal source to solve this issue.

2- When I use an external sender source, demultiplexing stops working, and seems the IC does not work! (Do you have any experience with other mux/demux ICs?) The datasheet gave the example of multiplexing, no idea for demux.

3- I tried to use Analog Switch e.g. CD74HC4066 but the number of pin-count for uC goes high.

The supply is as follows:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Thank you,
VHB

Comment: The pictue does not explain much how the muxes are used and for what purpose. How about more info and schematics?

Comment: A square wave should be provided for the senders and the Sending Elements (EL) has around 80pF capacity. I am working now with 4 MHz which should consume 10mA from the uC pin. The uC is STM32G483CET3 or STM32G473CET3.

Comment: A warm welcome to the site. This is new information and should be edited into your Question. Otherwise, readers have to piece all of this together to understand it. Please rewrite the question text as needed to contain this info, don't just dump it at the end under an 'EDIT' heading. Add information on how many pins, the purpose and much more. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers it will attract. Again, welcome.

Comment: The "microcontroller destroys itself" is a big red flag. Solve that first. You probably have a very fatal crosstalk into some supply line or such. Does your PCB layout have appropriate current return paths? How good and close is your decoupling?

Comment: Thank you @mmmm. Yes, I know the uC destroys itself, but why? I added the supply schematic too. There is nothing more! The PCB min tracks are 0.2 mm and with a clearance of 0.2 mm as well with the gold cover! I think it is well enough for 250mA or so! That is the max current that I do not reach.

Comment: You don't happen to have an oscilloscope with which you can observe how your 3.3 V develops?

Comment: Thank you @mmmm. Do you think a buck converter is required for this? I did not use it because I though 100mA does not need it.

Comment: It's probably not required. The problem might just be that the strong periodicity in your devices' current draw might resonate with your very generously dimensioned supply filter inductors. To figure that out, you should measure. Also, again, how's the current return paths?

Comment: All on all I think you're doing yourself a disservice with your inductors after the voltage regulator. The regulator's job, from the point of view of the consumer, is to react quickly to rapid current draw changes. Your inductor guarantees that cannot happen. Did you maybe mean to put the regulator directly attached to the microcontroller, and add the filter on the input side of the regulator? That way, you'd reduce crosstalk. You can try whether your system becomes better when you replace your inductors with shorts.

Comment: Without more load and signal measurements, nothing more can be said

Comment: Thank you all, I am going to do some more measurements. I also removed the inductor but no changes. I will do more evaluations. That's really amazing that I have such a problem. It is the first time that I encounter such a thing. I have several PCBs, circuits with the same setup (but smaller), same PCB rules, and working but this one...

Comment: your power tracks should be thicker than 0.2mm (8 thou). It's about the inductance, not the current carrying capacity, although 8thou tracks and some current = voltage drops.